# Tool for the Image documentation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, images, overlay

I want to document my images and looking for a tool like this as in the image below.

[image]

I want to highlight my image feature like the pink arrow, is there any tool for this to highlight features of an image? Or please recommend something similar to this.

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you already have Adobe Illustrator can't you just use that?

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry, I was looking for an easy to use tool, I don't have experience with AI.

Comment: Excuse me, but do you want a tool for documenting your images? I mean a tool for making a searchable content description, how it was made explanations and a preview, as much of this as possible automatically without writing manually long stories? If yes, give a report example and tell what should be automatic.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a screen capture app that has similar capabilities called ShareX - I believe it's for Windows only, and it's Open Source. Here's an example of what it can do below. All of the additions were made using the application. You can also use the software to create video and gif screen captures. I have no affiliation with the software or its developers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should look for a Screen Capture app like [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing-tool.html) (Mac & Windows): is free, easy to use and has several options for highlighting.

[image]

Comment: Or jings big brother... Snagit that is even better for this. The image was most likely done by snagit. Which is awesome for capturing long pages as it knows how to scroll the entire app and stitch to one large image

Comment: Jing is free 

Comment: Yes but its missing functions that you really ought to have. I calculated that when i was making documentation that snagit saved me 20€ per day. Free in this case is somewhat relative. Yeah i could have made it with jing and only save 5€ a day.